# Issue with using CSS on Iconic Icons in WordPress Theme.

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, ionicons

I would like to customize Ionicon using the css in Sequential WordPress theme. Iconic Icons was not originally in the theme. So I added by putting this code in functions.php.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bg_enqueue_ionicons' );
  function bg_enqueue_ionicons() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'ionicons', 
   '//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css', array());
  }
```

Then placing this code into footer.php. I would like to place the icon directly into footer without using widgets.

```
 <p class="social-icons">
   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/isaiah/"><i class="ion-social-linkedin-outline"></i></a>
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com/isaiah"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a>
   <a href="http://instagram.com/isaiah"><i class="icon ion-social-instagram-outline"></i></a>
   <a href="http://dribbble.com/isaiah"><i class="icon ion-social-dribbble-outline"></i></a>
 </p>
```

Finally adding the css, to make it look good. (***Issue Here***)

```
p.social-icons {
    border: 1px solid #949792;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 42px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 42px;
}

p.social-icons a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: red;
}
```

The icons will show but for some reason, the CSS will not apply. Does anybody have a fix for this?

Comment: Use the child of the parent: p.social-icons a { ...

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

your style should be like this.

```
 <style>
     p.social-icons a{
        border: 1px solid #949792;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: red;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 42px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 42px;
    }

    p.social-icons a:hover {
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: The code is already in a style sheet. This doesn't change anything.

Comment: I found the problem, my styles were being overwritten by code already in the theme. Thank you for checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Styles were being overwritten by a different class in the theme default style sheet.